# Running basic JavaScript in KML to be viewed through OpenLayers API

Tags: openstreetmap, kml, openlayers-2

I am trying to build an application in which points can be loaded on OSM map using KML called through OpenLayers with a balloon popup on each point. I am using the sample Sundials application: http://jorix.github.io/OL-FeaturePopups/examples/sundials-FP.html

I want to put a very simple album in the balloon using which the user can see more than one images within the balloon itself. I am sure this cannot be achieved without running some JS within the application. I thought I had a chance when I found the KMLs at: http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/javascript/

The scripts in these KMLs, when opened in Google Earth, works just fine but don't when called through OpenLayers. Upon digging in the developer tools it was revealed that the script part of the CDATA was not accessed and hence the function was declared undefined.

What would be a workaround for this? Any other way to view an album in a map popup?

Comment: You could extract the script into a string and call `eval()` on it. However, *"this cannot be achieved without running some JS within the application"* doesn't imply that JS has to be embedded in each point's handler. You could keep your code outside and only store corresponding HTML markup in KML's metadata.